# MapReduce Input Output selectivity

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am writing a MapReduce program and my requirement for the mapper is to output/emit **`x%`** of the map input file to be used as the reducer's input. Example if my file has `100` records then at `50%` threshold, the reducer's input should be only 50 records.

I have seen examples of getting Top N records but this is not what I want.

Comment: Your question is not quite clear. Can you be more specific with a real life example?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to achieve it,

1. Write custom InputFormat which accepts only X% of data.
2. Since the number of mappers will depend on InputSplit, write custom code in Mapper to emit only X% of data out of Mapper.
3. If your data is evenly distributed, you can use partitioner to pass X% of data to Reducer.

Answer (score -1):

The number of mappers spawned will be determined by number of `InputSplits` the input file is broken into. This number is generally determined by the underlying `HDFS` block size - each `InputSplit` will correspond to a `HDFS` block (e.g. 64 MB).  You can use `JobConf` [setNumMapTasks(int n)](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.3/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobConf.html#setNumMapTasks(int)), but this is only a hint to the framework.

If you want mapper output to be processed by a certain number of reducers, you can set this via two ways:

1. `SET mapreduce.job.reduces=n`
2. `JobConf` [setNumReduceTasks (int n)](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.3/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobConf.html#setNumReduceTasks(int)) method

This will use the default `HashPartitioner` and produce `n` partitions from the mapper output, which will be then processed by `n` reducers.

Comment: I am not sure how your answer relates to the question. You basically explained how to set the number of mappers and reducers which has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: My answer tries to explain how an input file is processed by mappers as per the `InputSplits`, instead of the number of records in a file. It appears you want to load balance across reducers, and hence the explanation on how to control number of reducers for a job. Hope it helps.